# Multi Threading - Request input once for all variables (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

Below are codes and outputs for a multithreading function whereby there is a counter and functions of add, subtract, multiply and divide. I'm using Eclipse.

4 Threads for each mathematical function:

```
public class Maths {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        CalculationThread T1 = new CalculationThread("Addition");
        T1.start();

        CalculationThread T2 = new CalculationThread("Subtraction");
        T2.start();

        CalculationThread T3 = new CalculationThread("Multiplication");
        T3.start();

        CalculationThread T4 = new CalculationThread("Division");
        T4.start();
    }
}

class CalculationThread extends Thread{
    private Thread t;
    private String maths;
    private int count = 0;
    private int resultplus, resultminus, resulttimes, resultdivide = 0;

    CalculationThread(String answer){
        maths = answer;
    }

    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Starting calculation of " + maths + "\n");
        if(t == null){
            t = new Thread (this, maths);
            t.start();
        }
    }
```

Here is where the functions take place, it will use the counters as 2 numbers to perform an equation.

```
    public void run(){
        try {
            for (int x=0; x<=3 ; x++){

                if(maths == "Addition"){
                System.out.println("Calculating: " + maths + " of " + count + 
                        " + "+ count + " = " + resultplus + "\n");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                count++;
                resultplus = count + count;
                }

                else if(maths == "Subtraction"){
                    System.out.println("Calculating: " + maths + " of " + count + 
                            " - "+ count + " = " + resultminus + "\n");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    count++;
                    resultminus = count - count;
                }

                else if(maths == "Multiplication"){
                    System.out.println("Calculating: " + maths + " of " + count + 
                            " * "+ count + " = " + resulttimes + "\n");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    count++;
                    resulttimes = count * count;
                }

                else if(maths == "Division"){
                    System.out.println("Calculating: " + maths + " of " + count + 
                            " / "+ count + " = " + resultdivide + "\n");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    count++;
                    resultdivide = count / count;
                }

            }

        }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("Math function failed");
            }
                if(maths == "Addition"){
                System.out.println("Addition completed.");
                }
                else if(maths == "Subtraction"){
                    System.out.println("Subtraction completed.");
                }
                else if(maths == "Multiplication"){
                    System.out.println("Multiplication completed.");
                }
                else if(maths == "Division"){
                    System.out.println("Division completed.");
                }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Starting calculation of Addition

Starting calculation of Subtraction

Calculating: Addition of 0 + 0 = 0

Starting calculation of Multiplication

Calculating: Subtraction of 0 - 0 = 0

Starting calculation of Division

Calculating: Multiplication of 0 * 0 = 0

Calculating: Division of 0 / 0 = 0

Calculating: Subtraction of 1 - 1 = 0

Calculating: Addition of 1 + 1 = 2

Calculating: Multiplication of 1 * 1 = 1

Calculating: Division of 1 / 1 = 1

Calculating: Addition of 2 + 2 = 4

Calculating: Subtraction of 2 - 2 = 0

Calculating: Division of 2 / 2 = 1

Calculating: Multiplication of 2 * 2 = 4

Calculating: Subtraction of 3 - 3 = 0

Calculating: Addition of 3 + 3 = 6

Calculating: Division of 3 / 3 = 1

Calculating: Multiplication of 3 * 3 = 9

Subtraction completed.
Addition completed.
Division completed.
Multiplication completed.
```

The code above works whereby all 4 functions will be done simultaneously , but whenever I try including a JOptionPane for user input instead of an automatic counter, each of the 4 threads will request at a time. Thus its not counted as multithreading if the functions are waiting for me to input 2 numbers. How and in what way can I include a user input that only requires user to input at the beginning so that all functions can use the 2 variables.

Comment: Side issue regarding: `if(maths == "Addition"){`: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: Another side issue: As described in the [documentation of the Thread class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), you should EITHER write a class that extends `Thread`, override the `run()` method, create an instance of your class, and call `start()`, OR write a class that implements `Runnable`, create an instance of your class, pass the instance to the constructor of `Thread`, then call `start()` on the `Thread` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer following codes.
Maybe it will suit your needs according to my understanding on your question. I also applied `.equals()` to the code according to Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggestion.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Maths {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Num1: ");
        String num2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Num2: ");
        int num11 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
        int num22 = Integer.parseInt(num2);

        calculationThread T1 = new calculationThread("Addition");
        T1.getNumber(num11, num22);
        T1.start();

        calculationThread T2 = new calculationThread("Subtraction");
        T2.getNumber(num11, num22);
        T2.start();

        calculationThread T3 = new calculationThread("Multiplication");
        T3.getNumber(num11, num22);
        T3.start();

        calculationThread T4 = new calculationThread("Division");
        T4.getNumber(num11, num22);
        T4.start();
    }
}

class calculationThread extends Thread{
    private Thread t;
    private String maths;
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int resultplus = 0;
    private int resultminus = 0;
    private int resulttimes = 0;
    private int resultdivide = 0;

    public void getNumber(int num1, int num2){
        a = num1;
        b = num2;
    }

    calculationThread(String answer){
        maths = answer;
    }

    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Starting calculation of " + maths + "\n");
        if(t == null){
            t = new Thread(this, maths);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            for (int x=0; x<=3 ; x++){
                if(maths.equals("Addition")){
                System.out.println("Calculating: " + maths + " of " + a + 
                        " + "+ b + " = " + resultplus + "\n");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                resultplus = a + b;
                }
                else if(maths.equals("Subtraction")){
                    System.out.println("Calculating: " + maths + " of " + a + 
                            " - "+ b + " = " + resultminus + "\n");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    resultminus = a - b;
                }
                else if(maths.equals("Multiplication")){
                    System.out.println("Calculating: " + maths + " of " + a + 
                            " * "+ b + " = " + resulttimes + "\n");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    resulttimes = a * b;
                }   
                else if(maths.equals("Division")){
                    System.out.println("Calculating: " + maths + " of " + a + 
                            " / "+ b + " = " + resultdivide + "\n");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    resultdivide = a / b;
                }   
            }   
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Math function failed");
        }
        finally{
            if(maths.equals("Addition")){
                System.out.println("Addition completed.");
            }
            else if(maths.equals("Subtraction")){
                System.out.println("Subtraction completed.");
            }
            else if(maths.equals("Multiplication")){
                System.out.println("Multiplication completed.");
            }
            else if(maths.equals("Division")){
                System.out.println("Division completed.");
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood it correctly.

If you just want to block the calculation threads and wait for an initial user Input you can use a `Semaphore`.

The UI Thread that waits for the user input shows the dialog and releases the waiting calculation threads by setting the number of permits / threads.

Here is an example how this could look like (it also uses an more object oriented approach). For simplicity, I've skipped the Multiplication and Division Tasks

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MathSample {

    // because updated / read from different threads mark as volatile 
    private volatile int a, b;

    // semaphore with no initial permits i.e.
    // the calculations will wait until permits are available.
    private Semaphore available = new Semaphore(0);

    private abstract class Task implements Runnable {

        public abstract void doCalculation();

        public abstract String getName();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // wait until a permit becomes available
                available.acquire();
                // not sure what should happen here
                // wait again for user input? 
                for (int x = 0; x < 50; ++x) {
                    a = a + x;
                    doCalculation();
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            System.out.println(String.format("Task %s completed.", getName()));
        }

    }


    private  class AdditionTask extends Task {

        public void doCalculation() {
            System.out.println(String.format("Calculating: Addition of + %d + %d = %d", a, b, a+b));
        }
        public String getName() {
            return "Addition";
        }
    }

    private  class SubstractionTask extends Task {
        public void doCalculation() {
            System.out.println(String.format("Calculating: Substraction of + %d - %d = %d", a, b, a-b));
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "Substraction";
        }
    }



    private void run() {
        new Thread(new AdditionTask()).start();
        new Thread(new SubstractionTask()).start();


        a = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("First value"));
        b = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Second value"));
        available.release(2); // let the 2 calculation threads run

    }


    public static void main(String ...args) {
        new MathSample().run();

    }
}
```

As you can see you don't have to overwrite the `start` method of the Thread  to run a different thread.

Your `start` method of your `CalculationThread` is at least strange because you overwrite the start method of the `Thread` class and within that you create another Thread instance where you pass your `CalculationThread` as `Runnable`.

Easier / better:

```
class Calculation implements Runnable {
   ...
   @override 
   public void run() {
      // the name you passed to the thread is your math 
      // lets get it from the currently running thread where it is stored.         
      final String math = Thread.currentThread().getName();
      ...
   }

}

// somewhere else 
new Thread(new CalculationThread, math).start();
```